# c++ Cannot use parent type as parameter in constructor

Tags: c++, g++

When trying to take an ancestor type as a parameter in a constructor g++ appears to be mistaking the type for the non existant default constructor. What's happening here, and is there a fix?

Minimal example:

```
class Outer
{
};

class Middle : Outer
{
    public:
    Middle(int i):i(i){}
    protected:
    int i;
};

class Inner : Middle 
{
    public:
    Inner(int i, Outer *o):Middle(i){}

};
```

g++ output:

```
example.h:16:18: error: ‘class Outer Outer::Outer’ is inaccessible within this context
     Inner(int i, Outer *o):Middle(i){}
                  ^~~~~
example.h:2:1: note: declared here
 {
 ^
```

Comment: Why are you using *private* inheritance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fully qualifier `Outer`, else it is private base which is inaccessible:

```
class Inner : Middle 
{
    public:
    Inner(int i, ::Outer *o):Middle(i){}

};
```

Or else use `protected`/`public` inheritance chain:

```
class Middle : public Outer
{
public:
    Middle(int i):i(i){}
protected:
    int i;
};

class Inner : public Middle 
{
public:
    Inner(int i, Outer *o):Middle(i){}
};
```